# How do I set "Audio" above "Diameter 18mm"

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is my project
https://jsfiddle.net/9rkfst5a/1/
How can I get the `h1` above the `ul` and not next to each other?

```js
let slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  let i;
  let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  let dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  overflow-x: hidden
}

body {
  font-family: 'SamsungOne', sans-serif;
}

a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.product {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 25px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  color: black;
}

.product ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  font: 50;
}

.product li {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.product ul #product-naam {
  font-size: xx-large;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

#ScrollToTop {
  position: fixed;
  right: 25px;
  bottom: 55px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  color: white;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
}

#ScrollToTop:hover {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}

.logo {
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  left: 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

.menubalk {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  color: black;
  align-items: center;
}

.menubalk li {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.name {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 853px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.411);
}

.fade {
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .7
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

.achtergrond {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.specs {
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

.cat {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.info {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  color: black;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.info li {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-right: 200px;
  margin-left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="icon" href="Images/logo-square-letter.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="buds-2.css" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="http://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/samsungone" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Samsung Galaxy Buds 2</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="ScrollToTop">
    <i class="material-icons">arrow_upward</i>
</button>
  <script>
    const ScrollToTop = document.querySelector("#ScrollToTop");

    ScrollToTop.addEventListener("click", function() {
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    });
  </script>
  <header>
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="index.html"><img src="Images/samsung-logo.png" alt="Samsung Logo" width="150"></a>
      <ul class="menubalk">
        <a href="mailto:thomas.lisabeth@sintjozefbrugge.be" target="_blank">
          <li>Contact</li>
        </a>
        <a href="index.html#assortiment">
          <li>Assortiment</li>
        </a>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>

  <div class="product">
    <ul>
      <li id="product-naam"><strong>Galaxy Buds 2</strong></li>
      <a href="#info">
        <li>test</li>
      </a>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="slideshow-container">
    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <img src="Images/Buds2-1.jpg" width="853">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <img src="Images/Buds2-2.jpg" width="853">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <img src="Images/Buds2-3.jpg" width="853">
    </div>

    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="specs">
    <h1 class="cat">Audio</h1>
    <ul class="info">
      <li>Diameter</li>
      <li>18mm</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: In the future, please make sure your code is provided in the *actual* post and not just a link to a jsfiddle or other external code editor. Take a look at [ask] and [mre] so that you can be prepared for when you're ready to ask your next question! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many ways, but simple and quick would be to just knock them out of the flow in your HTML so they're not contained in the specs class and then set the padding to 0 so the info isn't inheriting it.

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  overflow-x: hidden
}

body {
  font-family: 'SamsungOne', sans-serif;
}

a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.product {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 25px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  color: black;
}

.product ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  font: 50;
}

.product li {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.product ul #product-naam {
  font-size: xx-large;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

#ScrollToTop {
  position: fixed;
  right: 25px;
  bottom: 55px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  color: white;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
}

#ScrollToTop:hover {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}

.logo {
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  left: 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

.menubalk {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  color: black;
  align-items: center;
}

.menubalk li {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.name {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 853px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.411);
}

.fade {
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .7
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

.achtergrond {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.specs {
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

.cat {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.info {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  color: black;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 0;
}

.info li {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="icon" href="Images/logo-square-letter.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="buds-2.css" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="http://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/samsungone" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Samsung Galaxy Buds 2</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="ScrollToTop">
      <i class="material-icons">arrow_upward</i>
    </button>
  <script>
    const ScrollToTop = document.querySelector("#ScrollToTop");

    ScrollToTop.addEventListener("click", function() {
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    });
  </script>
  <header>
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="index.html"><img src="Images/samsung-logo.png" alt="Samsung Logo" width="150"></a>
      <ul class="menubalk">
        <a href="mailto:thomas.lisabeth@sintjozefbrugge.be" target="_blank">
          <li>Contact</li>
        </a>
        <a href="index.html#assortiment">
          <li>Assortiment</li>
        </a>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>

  <div class="product">
    <ul>
      <li id="product-naam"><strong>Galaxy Buds 2</strong></li>
      <a href="#info">
        <li>test</li>
      </a>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="slideshow-container">
    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <img src="Images/Buds2-1.jpg" width="853">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <img src="Images/Buds2-2.jpg" width="853">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <img src="Images/Buds2-3.jpg" width="853">
    </div>

    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="specs">
    <h1 class="cat">Audio</h1>
  </div>
  <ul class="info">
    <li>Diameter</li>
    <li>18mm</li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```